# Deleting a row with AJAX+php failing

Tags: php, jquery

The code should work the following way: Press a button -> row gets deleted from database.

I tried to follow and copy answers from other questions but with no working solution.

The jquery code:

```
$(document).on('click', ".menuRemove", function(event) {
  var del_h3name2 = $(this).parent().parent().prev().text();

  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'deleteaccordion2.php',
    data:{'del_h3name2':del_h3name2},
    success: function(data){
      if (data=="YES") {
        alert("YES")
      } else {
        alert("can't delete the row")
      }
    }
  });
}
```

and php code (deleteaccordion2.php):

```
<?php
  require 'database.php';

  if ( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {

    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $accordion = $_POST['del_h3name2'];

    echo '$accordion';

    $delete = "DELETE FROM useraccordion WHERE id='$id', h3= '$accordion' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($delete);

    if ($result) {
      echo "YES";
    } else {
      echo "NO";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Adding to what @Dekel said, do `alert(del_h3name2);` to see if you're getting correct `h3` column value to delete or not.

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` in database.php or somewhere in the page but just didn't include it here in your queation?

Comment: Terminus, it was missing but it didn't fix the issue. Thanks still.

Comment: Are you actually getting `"YES"` or `"NO"` back from deleteaccordian2.php?

Comment: I'm getting NO.

Comment: You're also missing a parameter for [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli_query). You can turn on error_reporting and display_errors while developing your site. Too much to explain in a comment but many resources available in the interwebs. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5438125) Good luck and happy programming!

Comment: Thanks for help. I'm even more newb when it comes to php, which shows!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't add the `html` so I really don't know if the value you are sending is correct, but you do have error in your SQL syntax:

```
 DELETE FROM useraccordion WHERE id='$id', h3= '$accordion'
                                         ^ This is wrong.
```

You can `DELETE` where `id = x AND h3 = y`:

```
$delete = "DELETE FROM useraccordion WHERE id='$id' AND h3= '$accordion' ";
```

> Note that your code is vulnerable for SQL injections (read about [boby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)).

Comment: The reason I didn't link any html is because the button and most of the html stuff is created dynamically in the jquery file. The button already deletes the correct elements from the website, but I'm having issues with the database. I also added AND but this didn't fix the issue, thanks for it anyway. Also SQL injections are something I will have to look into in future, this is just a hobby project so no rush.

Comment: Are you sure `del_h3name2 = $(this).parent().parent().prev().text();` gives you the correct value? Try `alert(del_h3name2)` (or check the network tab to see what value you actually send to the server). Without the HTML structure It's impossible to know what that value would be.

Comment: $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'deleteaccordion2.php',
        data:{'del_h3name2':del_h3name2},
        success: function(data){
           if(data=="YES"){
                alert(del_h3name2);
            }else{
               alert(del_h3name2);
           }
        }
       });    gives the correct del_h3name2 but still not working

Comment: Checking the network tab says following: Religion:"" --> is this the data sent to deleteaccordion2? I need it strictly to be Religion, without the : and ""

Comment: Based on your javascript code there should be `del_h3name2` with the value inside. If it's not there - you don't send it to the server. Did you add the `alert` I suggested?

Comment: Yes, now the network tab shows two deleteaccordion2.php messages when I press the delete button once. The first which fires in 83ms has form data of: Religion: and the second, which fires at 91ms has the following form data: del_h3name2:Religion

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand if you still have a problem (and what is it...)